# integer sequence 1,2,3,6,9,18,27,54

Tags: assembly, mips

I tried to generate an integer sequence: 1,2,3,6,9,18,27,54,81, and so on. This sequence is computed by adding the value to itself if it is odd, and by adding the previous value to it if it is even.
I have gone through my code so many times. I even tried to place numbers in there to test it by hand. However, I couldn't figure out what is the problem with my program. The machine still can't read it correctly. Please enlighten me on this. I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
.text
.globl main

 main:
 add $t0,$zero,$zero # initial index
 add $t1,$zero,1000  # terminate loop condition

        addi $at, $at, 1 #1
        add $v0,$at, $at #2
        add $v1,$v0,$at   #3
 L:     andi $a0,$v1,0x01 # check if 1 -> odd, 0 --> even
        beq $a0,$zero,isEven # check to see if it is even
        add $a1, $v1,$v1   # if it is odd, add to itself 
 isEven: add $a1, $v1,$v0     # add value of previous one
        add $v0,$zero,$v1 #v0 =3
        add $v1,$zero,$a1 #6
        addi $t0, $t0,1 # increase index
        bne $t0,$t1,L
```

Comment: There’s plenty of machine architectures. Would you mind editing the tags on your question to include what instruction set architecture you’re writing assembly for?

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what the problem is. Does the code not assemble (if so, what is the error message)? Does it crash (if so, where)? Does it generate the wrong sequence of numbers (if so, what sequence _is_ it generating)? Also, I suggest that you run your code in a simulator like SPIM or MARS. They have plenty of debugging features, so you can single-step through your code and inspect the values of all registers after each instruction.

Comment: There are no error message. it doesn't generate the right sequence of number. I used Mars to simulate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution in MIPS:

```
.data
space: .asciiz ", "
.text
li $t1, 1       #Start at 1
li $t2, 1       #Store last value
li $t4, 1000    #terminate at 1000
li $t7, 2       #For division (divide by 2)

loop:
li $v0, 1
add $a0, $t1, $zero #print $t1
syscall

div $t1, $t7      #divide $t1 by 2
mfhi $t5          #get the remainder
move $t6, $t1     #hang on to what $t1 was originally
beqz $t5, even    #if the remainder is 0, it's even

add $t1,$t1,$t1    #it's odd, so add to itself
move $t2, $t6      #store what $t1 was originally to last value
bgt $t1, $t4, done #if the number is over 1000, we're done
li $v0, 4           #Print a comma and space
la $a0, space
syscall
j loop
even:
add $t1,$t1,$t2    #set $t1 = $t1 + Last value ($t2)
move $t2, $t6      #store what $t1 was originally to last value
bgt $t1, $t4, done #if the number is over 1000, we're done
li $v0, 4           #Print a comma and space
la $a0, space
syscall
j loop
done:
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Rather than testing for even or odd, note that the pattern will always alternate between even and odd, since odd+odd is always even, and even + previous odd is always odd.

Comment: Very true @rcgldr - I just wrote it the way he described it.

Comment: You don't need `div` to test for divisibility by 2, just `andi $t5, $t1, 1` / `beqz $t5`.  Binary integers in registers are already in base 2, so you only need to check the low bit.